# How to arrange rows of a table in ascending order and to save the table simultaneously?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to create a new table by arranging the rows in ascending order from the existing table. The code I am trying to use is:

```
SELECT * 
   INTO new_table
FROM existing_table
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

However new table does not show any ascending arrangement of rows. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Rows in a table are by definition unordered.  Only a `select` with an `order by` guarantees an ordered set.

Comment: I know that but can the above command save it to a new table ?

Comment: But the code is working for me in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you know that why are you asking this question? It is nonsensical.

Comment: I'd vote not to close the question, since it's a very common misunderstanding that rows would by ordered. Perhaps it would be better to add an answer based on @Andomar 's comment....

Comment: @bummi - There must be many duplicates already that address this misconception.

Answer (score 2):

Rows in a table *are* unordered, so it doesn't make sense to talk about rows being in order.  And, the result set from a query is unordered, unless you use an `order by` clause.

That said, you can have the same effect of placing rows into a table in an ordered fashion.  Here is a method.

```
select top 0 *
into new_table
from existing_table;

alter table new_table add new_table_id int identity(1, 1);

insert into new_table(<list of columns without new_table_id>)
    SELECT <list of columns without new_table_id>
    INTO new_table
    FROM existing_table
    ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

The id column is guaranteed to be in the correct order.  In practice, it seems that the rows will be inserted in order.  Strictly speaking, the insert order is not guaranteed although the values of the id are ordered correctly.

As mentioned in the comment, you can also do:

```
alter table new_table add new_table_id int identity(1, 1) not null primary key;
```

You can do this because the table is empty.  As a primary key, the data should be inserted in order.

As a note, though.  The query:

```
select *
from new_table;
```

does not guarantee the ordering of the results.  It makes no difference what the insert order is into the table.  You cannot depend on the results being in a particular order just because the rows were ordered that way.  For instance, in a multi-threaded environment, the results *will generally not* be in order, either in theory or in practice.

Comment: As this is about SQL Server: physically the rows **are** ordered along the primary key because the PK is (by default) a clustered index (and thuse being ordered by the PK values). So one might actually say the table (which *is* the clustered primary key) is "ordered". But just to be clear: that does ***not*** imply or guarantee *any* order for the retrieval of the data unless an `order by` is used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I modified the answer.  I tend to forget you can add `not null` columns, because you cannot add them to an existing table (without a `default` value).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - There is absolutely no guarantee that rows stored in a clustered index will also be physically stored in that order in the file. Fragmentation can arise where this is not the case. A clustered index can be scanned in either allocation (physical) order or logical (index key) order.

Comment: Thank you for your nice effort but this code is not working..........my problem is: I have a table, I want to sort it and to save it in a new table (in a sorted format)... if I use this  SELECT * FROM existing_table ORDER BY col1, col2 it sorts the column in ascending order but this code does not help me to save the sorted table so I was trying to use  "SELECT * INTO new_table FROM existing_table ORDER BY col1, col2" to save the sorted results but when I open the new_table from the database it shows only existing_table (but no sorting)   ...

Comment: @RMZReza . . . If your problem is with `select into`, perhaps you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The script you quoted will not guarantee the order of data that is extracted from `new_table`.

You need to split it into two. Always apply the `ORDER BY` clause in the script that renders the output to whatever client you are using:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   new_table
FROM   existing_table

SELECT   *
FROM     new_table
ORDER BY col1, 
         col2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in MSSQL2012 if your **new_table** has a **PRIMARY KEY** in addition to col1 and col2.

```
INSERT INTO new_table
      (col1, col2)
SELECT (col1, col2)
FROM existing_table
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

First insert it into a temp table that has an identity column then the real table eg...

```
Declare @TempTable as table (
   id int identity (1,1),
   col1 varchar(255) null,
   col2 varchar(255) null
)

Insert into @TempTable 
select *
from existing_table
order by col1, col2

-- select * from @TempTable T  <--- Ive tested up to here and it works

insert into new_table (col1,col2)
select col1, col2
from @TempTable T
```