# How to sort a table by column inside of a database?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

I know it's possible by pulling the data from the table, manipulating it, and reinserting it, what I'm asking is if there's a query that can do it.

For example, the database is db.db has the table dogs. That table has the columns id,breed,age,name being in that id is the primary key and auto-increments (this primary key assumption can be changed for the sake of finding a good solution however).

I've searched around a lot but all places say the same thing, just do this:

```
$db->query("SELECT breed, age, name FROM Dogs ORDER BY Age DESC");
```

But, as I've said before, I want to sort the table. This kind of solutions apply to the results set, not the table itself, that's why I'm making this question.

**UPDATE:** I'm sorry for having mislead the people that read my question for not framing it properly, I intend on sorting all columns based on the Age column but the ID column can remain the same, if that helps, that's what I was trying to say with changing the primary key assumption but it came out wrong.

**UPDATE2** Found another question on stackoverflow that dealt with this subject exactly, the answer sort of matches the answer that has been given to me by user Quim Calpe, that is, create another table, do the stuff there, then copy it to the original table, now the question becomes, isn't there a better way of doing this that doesn't involve creating another table? I suppose it could become very resource-intensive if the table was extremely big to do all of those operations instead of letting the database system handle it in it's own way, if it has one that is...

Comment: so you want to reorder your table rows, based on the `Age`? Is there a reason for this? Typically you don't worry about the order until you need the results.

Comment: Why do you want to sort the table, not the result of the query? Databases don't store the data in a sorted sequence on disk, but provide the SQL "ORDER BY" clause for precisely the purpose of ordering a query result

Comment: @MarkBaker What [quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622509/how-to-arrange-rows-of-a-table-in-ascending-order-and-to-save-the-table-simultan) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725717/default-sort-ordering-in-mysql-alter-table-order-by) showed that they **may** be ordered but neither the table nor the fetch **guarantee** order (except if you use `ORDER BY`)

Comment: Data is actually stored in blocks on disk.... and many databases will typically use the first available block that contains sufficient space to hold the data being stored (or possibly span several blocks for larger data volumes).... storing data in a specific order would be additional overhead when storing data, potentially shuffling all subsequent data on disk, in much the same way PHP shuffles an array when using array_shift() or array_unshift() which are highly inefficient

Comment: "id can remain the same" - that makes no sense to me. What if you insert something later? Say it gets inserted between id1 and id2, now new item would be id2 and old id2 is id3 - defeats of having ids in the first place

Comment: @kingkero 1 - Nobody said insertions will work that way in my program so  you're just making stuff up. 2 - That's exactly what I want, so no, it doesn't defeat the purpose at all, it only does so inside your head. 3 - I asked a question because I need an answer, if you have no interest in helping you better spend your time doing something else.

Comment: @Sean There is a reason, the reason I want ID to be stationary and the rows ordered by Age is that I need to access the ordered results via a mathematical operation that spits out the ID's to access. That same mathematical operation cannot guess what is the number that's in the age field and cannot cope with repeated fields, hence the need for the ID even if it doesn't correspond to the same row everytime because of the sorting.

Comment: @MarkBaker I believe that you're right, and that I've explained myself incorrectly, please see my updates to the post.

Comment: @kingkero While I was searching some more about this subject I remembered your response and it struck me just how deeply absurd it really was, if sorting values without touching keys is something one would never do in your opinion then I wonder how you feel about functions like sort() in the php language, you must think they're all out of their damn minds right? (those guys that work with sort() and that implemented it and stuff...)

Comment: @wxiir - PHP arrays aren't like a database table at all, totally different datastructures for totally different purposes.... arrays  (based on a hashmap datastructure) do have an inherent order, which adds a lot of complexity and overhead if you want to insert new elements inside the array rather than at the end.... database tables don't use these datstructures, but use a basic bucket system which makes for fast insertion of new elements without ordering, and provide indexes to allow fast access to that data in an ordered manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<?php
$db->query("CREATE TABLE DogsSortedByAge LIKE Dogs");
$db->query("INSERT INTO DogsSortedByAge SELECT * FROM Dogs ORDER BY Age DESC");
```

But you don't have guarantees that data is going to be ordered that way on disk...

Can't think a valid use case for what your are asking...

Comment: After having a suitable response I was expecting on ordering all rows except for the ID one based on it, then I would be able to, by numerical ID, refer to columns by ordered Age, that's the use case I was thinking about, as I will only access the table by ordered Age but I will never actually use the Age column for that but the ID column instead. I will re-state my question to account for this.

Comment: Could you find a better way that doesn't involve creating a new table if the target columns were all of them except the ID column? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it won't help me further as I'll leave this PDO/SQL crap for the sake of my mental sanity. I'm fed up. The last week I tested how my CMS would be if it worked with a proper database instead of flatfiles with php arrays and stuff. Supposedly knowledgeable people told me to try it out. Databases have better performance and are soooo easy and flexible to manipulate they said. My code is now much bigger than the equivalent flatfile/array code because I have to keep finding hacks to do what would be trivial with arrays and flatfiles, its absurd. //End_rant